# When to call takeTurn() to skip starting player's turn

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, multiplayer, google-play-games

I am using google's turn based multiplayer API in my android application. I see that the `takeTurn()` method is already called in `startMatch()` in the project that they provide for reference.

I know I need to call `takeTurn()` in order to skip over the player's turn that started the game so that the first player is not able to interact with the view until a player has joined the match and has taken their turn first. I am just not positive where I need to make the `takeTurn()` call in order to do this since it is already called in the `onStart()` method.

It makes me think that I would need to call it when a button is pressed to start a game but since `onStart()` is called in that process and `onStart()` calls `takeTurn()` it seems redundant to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason to call `takeTurn()` at the start is to notify the other play of the Turn-Based game.  The other player is not notified until the first player has taken his/her turn.

There is no set place you should call it, and it is not recommended or required to skip the first player's turn.  It is just an option.